# Hidden Schemes if third location is a sea zone?

Tags: fury-of-dracula

The `Hidden Schemes` Event card states:

> If there is a hideout on the third space of the trail, place an encounter card on it.

The rules don't seem to be clear about how to resolve this event when the third location on the trail is a sea zone.

**If the third location on the trail is a sea zone when `Hidden Schemes` is played, should an encounter card be placed?**

Answer (score 2):

Dracula is not allowed to place an encounter card on a sea zone under any circumstances.

The Rules Reference entry on "Hideouts" should have specified only non-sea locations are hideouts, which would have removed any ambiguity.